# Launch PHP app (WordPress) from command line for development?

Tags: php, ruby, wordpress, apache, sinatra

I have been hacking on Ruby/Sinatra recently, and love it.  Now I need to use WordPress again after several years.

I'm not a big of XAMPP and MAMP (I'm on a Mac), because they have rigid requirements where to put your files, and seem generally huge and monolithic.  I want to keep my PHP projects in discrete folders, among my other projects.

Is there any way to run a lightweight Apache/PHP development instance, from a directory, with the command line?  I'd like to access a site via `http://localhost:XXXX/` where XXXX is an arbitrary port number.  Very similar to how Rails or Sinatra/Shotgun works.

Otherwise, what is the recommended, lightweight way to run PHP in 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP 5.4.0 introduced a [built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). This should be what you are looking for.

Edit: It seems to be possible to [run wordpress on it](http://ripeworks.com/run-wordpress-locally-using-phps-buily-in-web-server/)

```
<?php

$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
chdir($root);
$path = '/'.ltrim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'],'/');
set_include_path(get_include_path().':'.__DIR__);
if(file_exists($root.$path))
{
if(is_dir($root.$path) && substr($path,strlen($path) - 1, 1) !== '/')
$path = rtrim($path,'/').'/index.php';
if(strpos($path,'.php') === false) return false;
else {
chdir(dirname($root.$path));
require_once $root.$path;
}
}else include_once 'index.php';
```

> Drop this script in your project, and off you go!

```
$ php -S localhost:9393 -t /path/to/wordpress router.php
```

> If you placed router.php inside your wordpress directory, don’t bother with the -t flag. That is to specify an alternative document root.

Comment: @hakre edit my answer to include ideas and reference of how to run wordpress on it.

Comment: This worked for me.  For the record, I upgraded my Homebrew to PHP 5.5.3, which (with the SQLite Integration plugin) seems to run WordPress just fine without the router code you supplied.  Thanks regardless.